# How to check rows are true in grid view databound event?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, aspxgridview

I have a Gridview with one button, if all rows are true or checked then button state set to enabled otherwise it will be disable.
here is my code but it doesn't work for me.

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then


        Dim ckbox As CheckBox = CType(e.Row.FindControl("workfinished"), CheckBox)

        If ckbox.Checked = True Then
            btnFinishedAllWork.Enabled = True

        End If



    End If
```

[image]

Comment: What event in server-side is your VB.Net code that you have given in your post?

Comment: Hi @Sunil I used the RowDataBound of GridView.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Note that in my answer, the button is being disabled in row data bound event as opposed to being enabled. You were enabling the button in this same event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use sample code mentioned below to implement your requirements.

The important points are as below.

- Always set the enabled state of button to true at start of page life cycle in Page_Load event
- Then, when grid data row is being bound, which happens after the Page_Load event, you set the button state to disabled when any of the check boxes is unchecked

**VB.NET code below to change button state**

```
''In Page_Load event set the button to enabled state and then change its state later
''in page life cycle depending on if a check box is unchecked.

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

btnFinishedAllWork.Enabled = True

End Sub



Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim ckbox As CheckBox = CType(e.Row.FindControl("workfinished"), CheckBox)
        ''only change the state of button any one of the check boxes is unchecked
        If ckbox.Checked = False Then
            btnFinishedAllWork.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```